# How to make socket read function non-blocking

Tags: sockets, pthreads, nonblocking

Is there a way by which I can make a socket read function as non-Blocking.I have a multithreaded server application, I want that my accept() function should be a blocking one,but the read() function should be non-Blocking and should return EAGAIN when there is no data to  be read.

I tried making read() non-Blocking by

```
fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

but it started giving me resource temporarily unavailable error.

Comment: The function `int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);` supports the option `O_NONBLOCK` as type. Have you tried using it ?

Comment: @Omar yes I am using the above.

Comment: @Omar: Fresher is calling `accept()` and wants it to be blocking, so `O_NONBLOCK` cannot be used on the listening socket. Even if it were, `O_NONBLOCK` is not inherited by the accepted client sockets, so it has to be applied using `fcntl()` on each individual client socket after being accepted.

Comment: @Fresherdeveloper: If `fcntl()` is not working for you, you are probably using it wrong. Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, you can use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to detect when data is available before then calling `read()` to read it, then you don't have to use non-blocking mode at all.

Answer (score 2):

*"Resource temporarily unavailable"* is `EAGAIN`.

It is working correctly.